# How to define port dynamically in proxy.conf.json or proxy.conf.js

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have angular4 application, and for development purposes i start it with `npm run start` with `start` defined as `"start": "ng serve  --proxy=proxy.conf.json"`. Also I have

```json
{
    "/api/**": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/api/"
    }
}
```

defined in `proxy.conf.json`.
Is there a way, to define port or whole url dynamically. Like `npm run start --port=8099`?

**PS**

`http://localhost:8080/api/` is URL of my backend API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also did not find way to interpolate .json file but you can use .js file

e.g.

proxy.conf.js

```
var process = require("process");
var BACKEND_PORT = process.env.BACKEND_PORT || 8080;
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/api/**"
        ],
        target: "http://localhost:"+BACKEND_PORT+"/api/
    },
];
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

add new command to package.json (notice .js not .json)

```
"startOn8090": "BACKEND_PORT=8090 && ng serve --proxy=proxy.conf.js"
```

or simply set env variable in your shell script and call `npm run-script start`

Answer (score 0):

In `.angular.cli.json`

```
....
"defaults": {
  "serve": {
    "port": 9000
  }
}
....
```

makes the proxy available on port 9000 rather than the default 4200.

Comment: It makes angular frontend run on another port, not proxying requests to another port. And edit of file is not a thing i want anyway. I already can edit proxy.conf.js* file.

Comment: I can, but... I don't want to depend of free pprts on different dev. machines. It is realy local parameter. This file is under git, if one dev change it, according to his config, it will broke job for all others. I can do this on my backend, why not to try  here? Get it from commandline,  env, or elsewhere!.

Comment: @glebiuskv Have you found solution?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov No :(